# Help converting spherical to cartesian?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

> Convert the following equation from spherical to coordinate:
>   sin<sup>2</sup>(ϕ) + cos<sup>2</sup>(ϕ)⁄4 = 1/ρ<sup>2</sup>;

I have converted the right side of the equation to 1/x<sup>2</sup>+y<sup>2</sup>+z<sup>2</sup>, but the fraction on the left side of the equation is throwing me off. Any advice/help/solutions?

Answer (score 2):

$x = \rho\cos\theta\cos\phi\\
y = \rho\sin\theta\cos\phi\\
z = \rho\sin\phi$

$\sin^2\phi + \frac 14 \cos^2\phi = \frac 1{\rho^2}\\
\rho^2\sin^2\phi + \frac 14 \rho^2 \cos^2\phi = 1\\
z^2 + \frac 14 \rho^2 \cos^2\phi = 1$

$x^2+y^2 = \rho^2 \cos^2\phi$

$z^2 + \frac 14 x^2 + \frac 14 y^2  = 1$

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much. So would it be the same sort of thing for:

Comment: cos(φ) = ρsin^2(φ)?

Comment: $\cos\phi = \rho \sin^2\phi \implies \rho\cos\phi = \rho^2\sin^2\phi\implies \sqrt {x^2+y^2} = z^2$  Or someone has swapped the direction $\phi$ sweeps out, (i.e. $\phi = 0$ can be the "north pole" or it can be the equator.) in which case $z = x^2 + y^2$